# Program doesn't return values to function

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, switch-statement, return

I am trying to make a newtons 2nd law calculator and when I enter the values for the calculation nothing happens. I am not sure if they aren't being returned to the main function or what. What I wanted to do was have the user input a character which was then taken by a function containing a switch statement, in the cases of the switch statement would function calls to functions that did the arithmetic, those functions would then return a value to the switch function and the switch function would return a value to the main function which would then print the value to the screen.

```
// Newtons2ndlaw.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program 
execution begins and ends there.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>

void varselect(char, float *);

void force(float *);

void acceleration(float *);

void mass(float *);

int main()


{

    float eqvalue;
    char operation;

    printf("Welcome to Newtons 2nd law solver!\n");

    system("PAUSE");

    printf("Would you like to solve for a Force, Acceleration or Mass?\nType 'F'(for force), 'A'(for acceleration), 'M'(for mass) to select a variable\n");

    scanf_s("%c", &operation,1);
    if (operation == 'f' || operation == 'F' || operation == 'a' || operation == 'A' || operation == 'm' || operation == 'M')           //logic for determing what the user entered
    {}
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid character.");
    }

     varselect(operation,&eqvalue);             //function call to receive float value from varselect function

     if (operation == 'f' || operation == 'F')              //{
     {
         printf("The force = %f",eqvalue);
     }
                                                                //this block determines what character string to display with calculated float value                                    
     else if (operation == 'a' || operation == 'A')                         
     {
         printf("The acceleration = %f", eqvalue);
     }

     else if (operation == 'm' || operation == 'M')
     {
         printf("the Mass = %f", eqvalue);
     }
}                                                           //}

void varselect(char x, float *j)                            
                                                                    //this function recieves the user inputed char value and returns the calculated float value to function call. 
{                                                                   //switch allows program to "understand" users unwillingness to press shift before a,f,m like printf statement tells them to do.
    switch (x)                                                      // also allows each variable to call its own function.
    {
    case 'f':
        float getval;
        force(&getval);
        *j = getval;
        return;
        break;
    }

    switch (x)
    {
    case 'F':
        float getval;
        force(&getval);
        *j = getval;
        return;
        break;
    }

    switch (x)
    {
    case 'a':
        float getval;
        acceleration(&getval);
        *j = getval;
        return;
        break;
    }

    switch (x)
    {
    case 'A':
        float getval;
        acceleration(&getval);
        *j = getval;
        return;
        break;
    }

    switch (x)
    {
    case 'm':
        float getval;
        mass(&getval);
        *j = getval;
        return;
        break;

    }

    switch (x)
    {
    case 'M':
        float getval;
        mass(&getval);
        *j = getval;
        return;
        break;
    }
    return;
}

void force(float *fma)                                      
{
    float acceleration, mass;

    printf("Enter a value for 'Mass', then 'Acceleration'.\n\n");
    scanf_s("%f\n%f\n", &mass, &acceleration, 2);

        *fma = mass * acceleration;

        return;

}

void acceleration(float *afm)
{                                                                                                                           //functions to take input from user and return float to varselect function
    float force, mass;

    printf("Enter a value for 'Force', then 'Mass'.\n\n");
    scanf_s("%f\n%f\n", &force, &mass, 1);

        *afm = force / mass;

    return;

}

void mass(float *fam)
{
    float force, acceleration;

    printf("Enter a value for 'Force', then 'Acceleration'.\n\n");
    scanf_s("%f\n%f\n", &force, &acceleration, 1);

    *fam = force / acceleration;

    return;
}
```

Comment: you need to learn how to debug your own programs. And you need to create a [MCVE] . Question where you dump all of your program and say "it doesn't work" will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: This is not how `switch` should be used. You need at most one `switch` statement in your `varselect` function.

Comment: Prefer `float force()` over `void force(float *fma)`. The intent of the function is much clearer. In the first it's obvious you are computing and returning. In the second you don't know what's going on with that pointer until you read the code. Could be the function expects an array. Could be updating a value, but in that case it should be `void force(float & fma)`. This is C++ after all. Which brings up the question, what's up with all this `printf` and `scanf_s` stuff? That's not even a Standard-compliant `scanf.

Comment: Sorry about the way the question is presented, this is the first time I've been on this forum. I'm taking a course on C this semester and this program is just me exploring around it. I do see what you are saying about the switch statements! I will try playing with the functions like you suggest as well! The reason I used scanf_s is because in visual it gave me a compiler error when using scanf. It wanted me to use scanf_s so I could specify a buffer limit. What should I use other than printf? I am not aware of anything as this is my first exposure to C programming.

Answer (score -1):

I think its notting to do with your code... What i can say is that if you have an int or double or float function it works the same as void. You put in the parameters that you need, maybe like for the Newton's second law or whatever you need. And there you can add the switch function. And after the switch you return the output.
After the switch after its {} you put return output or the name of the variable you want to return.
To get it on the console you just make like this:
std::cout<<(function name) output(/*variables that are in the function parameter or whatever */ 13, 4.0f) <